# error message it must be logical vector not a double

Tags: r

```
Data_passed <- Data %>% filter(grade >= 5 )
Data_passed_slim <- Data %>% filter(student )
Data_passed_slim <- Data %>% filter(course )
```

I write those,Data_passed <- Data %>% filter(grade >= 5 ) it is ok.

1.Data_passed_slim <- Data %>% filter(student )

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.

i Input `..1` is `student`.
x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a double

2.Data_passed_slim <- Data %>% filter(course )

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `course`.
x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a character

Comment: What is the `class(Data$student)` `filter` expects a logical vector as input `grade >= 5` is logical and `student` may not be (as showed in the error that it is a numeric class.  What do you expect by `filter(student)`

Comment: @akrun it is numbers like 23133.I mean the class student it has numbers like 21939

Comment: ok thanks.  what is your expected when you do `filter(student)`

Comment: to create a new object Data_passed_slim

Comment: Your description is not clear.  what is the condition in `filter` to subset the rows of 'Data' to create Data_passed_slim

Comment: Maybe you need `Data_passed_slim <- Data %>% select(student)` instead of `filter`

Comment: yes that what I need it

Comment: answer it so I will accept it to thank  you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to return a single column, use `select` instead of `filter` as `filter` expects a logical expression

```
library(dplyr)
Data_passed_slim <- Data %>% 
                     select(student)
```